# Per-configuration classpath dependencies doesn't work with test->test in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've got a multi-project build with `scalania` main project as well as `exercises` and `answers` (sub)projects.

[The scalania project](https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/scalania) is hosted on GitHub.

I'm trying to set up a SBT project configuration where the test classes are part of the `exercises` project while the `answers` project provides the solutions.

I read [Per-configuration classpath dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#per-configuration-classpath-dependencies) in the official documentation of SBT and ended up with the following configuration in the `scalania` main project:

```
lazy val exercises = project

lazy val answers = project.dependsOn(exercises % "test->test")
```

It doesn't seem to work and upon `test` execution I used to get:

```
> project answers
[info] Set current project to scalania-answers (in build file:/Users/jacek/oss/scalania/)
> test
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for answers/test:test
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 27, 2013 1:06:51 AM
```

It was until I changed `answers/build.sbt` to the following:

```
scalaSource in Test := (scalaSource in LocalProject("exercises") in Test).value
```

It works fine now.

```
> reload
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/project
[info] Set current project to scalania-answers (in build file:/Users/jacek/oss/scalania/)
> project answers
[info] Set current project to scalania-answers (in build file:/Users/jacek/oss/scalania/)
> testOnly *s99.P01*
[info] Formatting 19 Scala sources {file:/Users/jacek/oss/scalania/}answers(test) ...
[info] Compiling 19 Scala sources to /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/answers/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
[info] P01Spec
[info]
[info] P01 solution should
[info] + Find the last element of a list
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for specification P01Spec
[info] Finished in 151 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
[success] Total time: 74 s, completed Oct 27, 2013 1:09:07 AM
```

What's wrong with using `project.dependsOn(exercises % "test->test")` only? Am I missing something in the build configuration?

Comment: Is the problem that you have test classes in one subproject `exercises` and you are trying to run them in another subproject `answers` that just depends on `exercises`?

Comment: Yes. That's the problem I'd love sorting out in idiomatic way in SBT. Let me know @MarkHarrah if there's such a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a dependency on tests in another project just makes the classpath available.  Running its tests doesn't happen by default because otherwise tests would run multiple times in the common situation of just reusing code.

To run tests in another project, add the discovered tests from the other project to those for the current project:

```
definedTests in Test := 
   (definedTests in Test).value ++
   (definedTests in exercises in Test).value
```